# estoy teniendo un problema , cuando quiero hacer una peticion desde mi APi a mi Base de datos SQLServer

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Internal connection fatal error.'
```

El problema que me arroja es este , y la cadena de conexion utilizada es:

```
conexion = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Elenia2;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=False");
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y alguna vez te pudiste conectar?

Comment: puedes intentar con esto para obtrener mas detalles del error: `try
{
    // Tu código de conexión aquí
    conexion.Open();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error al abrir la conexión: {ex.Message}");
    // Puedes agregar más información del error si está disponible
}`

Comment: es un try ... catch ...

Answer (score 0):

```
conexion = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Elenia2;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=False;");
```

puede ser un tema de formato, termina con punto y coma dentro de las comillas.

Comment: Si esto fuera el problema, se cierra como que es un error tipografico, y se deja un comentario.. esperemos a ver si es ese el problema...

Answer (score 0):

Estos serian dos ejemplos de como deberia de ir tu cadena de conexion

```
 "Server=nombreServer;Database=nombreDB; User Id=usuarioDB; Password=passwordDB; TrustServerCertificate=True;"

string conexion = @"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Elenia2;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=False";
```

Si la autenticacion es por medio de Windows y no necesariamente por usuario y contraseña, omite esos campos o bien coloca Encrypt=False;

espero te sirva, saludos!